# orthogonal polynomials and weight functions

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

how are orthogonal polynomials related to their weight function? is there an algebraic relationship other than the defining integral
$$\int_a^b w(x)P_n(x)P_m(x)\,dx$$?

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

If one is given a second order linear differential operator of the form $$L(f) \equiv a(x)f''(x)+b(x)f'(x)+c(x)f(x)$$ and one wishes to know for which Hilbert space $L$ constitutes a Hermitian operator, one puts $L$ into the form known as Sturmian form $$L(f) \equiv \frac{1}{r(x)}\big((p(x)f'(x))'+q(x)f(x)\big)$$ where it is simple to show that $$p(x)=e^{\int \frac{b(x)}{a(x)}}$$ $$r(x)=\frac{p(x)}{a(x)}$$ and $$q(x)=r(x)c(x)$$

Then $r(x)$ is the natural weighting function to use in order to turn $L$ into a Hermitian operator (one still needs to add boundary constraints) and the eigenvalue solutions to $L$ will form an orthogonal basis for the constructed Hilbert space. See Holland's 'Applied Analysis by the Hilbert Space Method' for details and proofs. Good question!

Comment: is it possible to go from just knowing the weight function and the boundaries to the differential operator?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but my intuition tells me that up to a constant one can.

Comment: The derivative should be on $f$, not on $p$. (Otherwise you'd have no $f''$ term.)

Comment: @joriki Indeed, thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

To say that the polynomials are orthogonal implicitly references the inner product $$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_a^b f(x)g(x)w(x)dx$$ The closest thing I can think of to an algebraic relationship between the polynomials and the weight function is the requirement that
$$\langle P_n, P_m \rangle = \delta_{nm}$$

Comment: So the weight function turns the integral as the Polynomials were already orthonormal?